# Notice: Undefined variable: cod2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemaOriginal\ajax\agregar_compras.php on line 33

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hola amigos quisiera su ayuda con lo siguiente,
me aparece el siguiente error Notice: Undefined variable: cod2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemaOriginal\ajax\agregar_compras.php on line 33```

1. este es mi codigo:

````
if (isset($_POST['id'])){$id=$_POST['id'];}
if (isset($_POST['cantidad'])){$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];}
if (isset($_POST['precio_venta'])){$precio_venta=$_POST['precio_venta'];}
if (isset($_POST['stock'])){$stock=$_POST['stock'];}
if (isset($_POST['code'])){$cod=$_POST['code'];}
if (isset($_POST['code2'])){$cod2=$_POST['code2'];}```

2. y aqui es donde hago el insert:

```$insert_tmp=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tmp 
(id_producto,cantidad_tmp,precio_tmp,session_id,tienda,cod,Renglon_Presupuestario) VALUES 
('$id','$cantidad','$precio_venta','$session_id','$stock','$cod','$cod2')");```
````

Comment: Creo que tu ejemplo es bastante escaso. Además tu error dice que tienes una variable que no está definida en la línea 33.

Comment: que mas información necesitas amigo?

Comment: Solo declara arriba, ya que si el `if` no se cumple, la variable nunca se declararia. Esto para todas tus condiciones tambien

Answer (score 1):

Estás declarando variables solo si fueron recibidas en `$_POST`. Si las vas a necesitar posteriormente, deberías declararlas siempre.

**Opción 1:** Declarar antes de las condicionales:

```
// Declarar variables con valores por defecto
$id = 0;
$cantidad = 0;
$precio_venta = 0;
$stock = 0;
$cod = '';
$cod2 = '';

// Analizar si cada variable viene en $_POST para actualizar valor
if(isset($_POST['id'])) { $id=$_POST['id']; }
if(isset($_POST['cantidad'])) { $cantidad=$_POST['cantidad']; }
if(isset($_POST['precio_venta'])) { $precio_venta=$_POST['precio_venta']; }
if(isset($_POST['stock'])) { $stock=$_POST['stock']; }
if(isset($_POST['code'])) { $cod=$_POST['code']; }
if(isset($_POST['code2'])) { $cod2=$_POST['code2']; }
```

**Opción 2:** Declarar usando [asignación ternaria](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
// Hazlo para todas las variables, aquí solo un par de ejemplos
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;
$cod = (isset($_POST['code'])) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
```

**Opción 3:** Declarar con [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
// Hazlo para todas las variables, aquí solo un par de ejemplos
$id = $_POST['id'] ?? 0;
$cod = $_POST['code'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Gracias amigo si me sirvió