# Undefined variable: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoApps\registra.php on line 27

Tags: php

He estado intentando guardar datos en una base de datos utilizando codigo php, y ya logre identificar y modificar muchos de mis errores, pero simplemente no entiendo que hacer con este error, o como corregirlo y lograr que funcione.

````
<?php   

// Recibimos por POST los datos procedentes del formulario   

if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
   $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
}




  

// Abrimos la conexion a la base de datos   
include("abre_conexion.php"); 
if($conexion_db){
echo "todo correcto";
}   

$_GRABAR_SQL = "INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (Nombre) VALUES ('$nombre')";   //Esta vendria siendo la linea 27
mysqli_query($conexion_db,$_GRABAR_SQL);  

// Cerramos la conexion a la base de datos   
include("cierra_conexion.php");   

// Confirmamos que el registro ha sido insertado con exito   

echo "   
<p>Los datos han sido guardados con exito.</p>   

<p><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>VOLVER ATRÁS</a></p>   
";   
?>    ```
````

Comment: Claramente te está diciendo que la variable `nombre` no está definida. Luego del primer IF haz un var_dump() de nombre, y verás que sucede

Comment: Tu problema es el mismo de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/442619/54039)